# Python - Group Concat rows based on criteria

Tags: python, string, concatenation, group-concat

I am a Python beginner. I need to do a group concatenate. I tried different ways but couldn't come up with anything final.

I have a dataset:

```
A   Apple  
A   Orange  
A   Peach  
B   Apricot  
C   Banana  
B   Cherry  
C   Blueberry
```

I need to group it to the following format

```
A   Apple, Orange, Peach  
B   Apricot, Cherry  
C   Banana, Blueberry
```

Any Ideas. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: when you say dataset.. do you mean in a file or in a list or?

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.groupby` https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: Its an excel file. about 30000 line items

Comment: What did you try? You should post your best effort.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this solves your problem:

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()
    f.close()
    words = {}
    for line in file.split('\n'):
        letter, word = line.split(' ')
        try:
            words[letter] = words[letter] + [word]
        except KeyError:
            words.update({letter: [word]})

# id = 'A' or 'B' Etc.
for id, word in sorted(words.items()):
    print('{0} {1}'.format(id, word))
```

**Output:**

```
A ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Peach']
B ['Apricot', 'Cherry']
C ['Banana', 'Blueberry']
```

**What it is doing:**

1. Opens your `.txt` file and reads it. Once done it closes it.
2. Splits the file into each line, and iterates over each line.
3. Splits line into each letter and word. Then places those values into `letter` and `word`.
4. Tries to add `word` the list of values at the key of the letter in `words`.
5. If failed(Key doesn't exist), it adds it as a new key and value.
6. Loops over each one and prints out nicely :)

Comment: Also the file handling is not too good. You shouldn't read the entire file into memory; it's better to iterate over the file object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open('input') as f:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for key, word in (line.split() for line in f):
        d[key].append(word)

    for k in sorted(d):
        print('{} {}'.format(k, ', '.join(sorted(d[k]))))
```

**Output**

```
A Apple, Orange, Peach
B Apricot, Cherry
C Banana, Blueberry
```

The `defaultdict` makes collecting items into lists much easier than managing a standard dictionary because you don't need to check whether a key is already in the dictionary before adding it.

Another option is to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), but that requires the data to be in order, and would therefore require that you sort the file before use.